# Get query string in Google CSE v2

Tags: ajax, google-custom-search

I am using Google CSE v2, and I need to get the query that the user entered. The problem is that it is ajax, and the query is not in the url.

Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, when you create the search box, you need to give it a 'gname' attribute so you can identify it in your javascript, like so:

```
<gcse:searchbox gname="storesearch"></gcse:searchbox>
<gcse:searchresults gname="storesearch"></gcse:searchresults>
```

Or, if you're using the html5 style tags (which you should unless you have a reason not to):

```
<div class="gcse-searchbox" data-gname="storesearch"></div>
<div class="gcse-searchresults" data-gname="storesearch"></div>
```

(Replace 'storesearch' with whatever name you want to use to identify this custom search.)

More info on that here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#supported_attributes

Then, you can access the custom search element and get the current query like so:

```
var cseElement = google.search.cse.element.getElement('storesearch'),
query = cseElement.getInputQuery();
```

or if you don't need the reference to the element anymore, obviously that could be combined into one line:

```
var query = google.search.cse.element.getElement('storesearch').getInputQuery();
```

The docs for that part are here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#cse-element

Comment: Is there something you need to have setup to use the google.search.cse.element functions? It complains about google not being defined but the search box itself works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered correctly. But for those also looking for a simple JS function to achieve this, here you go. Pass it the name of the variable you want to extract from the query string.

```
var qs = (function(a) {
  if (a == "") return {};
  var b = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    var p=a[i].split('=');
    if (p.length != 2) continue;
      b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }
  return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```